# Density of permutation of syndetic sets of integers

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

Define the upper uniform density of a set $A\subset\mathbb{Z}$ to be 
$$
D^+(A)=\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{a\in\mathbb{R}}\frac{|A\cap[a,a+r)|}{r}
$$
Fix an arbitrary permutation of the integers $\omega:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ ( i.e. $\omega$ is a bijection) and let $\varepsilon>0$.

Does there exist a syndetic set $A\subset\mathbb{Z}$ (syndetic means it has bounded gaps, or equivalently that there exists some positive $n$ such that $A$ has nonempty intersection with any interval of length $n$) such that 
$$
D^+(\omega(A))<\varepsilon
$$

Comment: For some choices of $\omega$ this is clearly impossible (e.g., if $\omega$ is the identity map, or if it fixes arbitrarily long initial segments), and for other choices it is possible. Do you want to put some restrictions on the kinds of bijections you're interested in?

Comment: @WillBrian I think $n$ is allowed to depend on $\epsilon$, so for the identity map it is obviously possible.

Comment: @SeanEberhard: Ah, thanks! This makes much more sense now.

Comment: Indeed $n$ is allowed to depend on $\varepsilon$ and so the identity (or any density preserving permutation) clearly satisfies this condition.

Comment: To be more accurate, think that $\varepsilon$ is also fixed and the task is to show that there exists any syndetic set $A$ s.t. its image under the fixed permutation would have small density. At this point I would be happy with being able to show such syndetic set exists, but of course a construction is much desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Let $\mathbb{Z} = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty I_i$ be a decomposition of $\mathbb{Z}$ into disjoint intervals of length $n$. We will find $A\subset\mathbb{Z}$ such that $|A\cap I_i| = 1$ for each $i$ and such that $|\omega(A)\cap I_i|\leq 1$ for each $i$. Thus $A$ is syndetic and $D^+(\omega(A)) \leq 1/n$.

Define an infinite bipartite graph $\mathcal{G}$ with vertex classes $U$ and $V$, both of which are indexed by $\mathbb{N}$. Put an edge between $i\in U$ and $j\in V$ whenever $\omega(I_i)\cap I_j\neq\emptyset$. Moreover give each edge $ij$ the weight $|\omega(I_i)\cap I_j|$. Then for every vertex $v\in \mathcal{G}$, the total weight of the edges incident with $v$ is exactly $n$. From this it follows that Hall's marriage condition is satisfied, since for finite $A\subset U$ we have
$$
  n |A| = \sum_{i\in A} \sum_{j\sim i} w_{ij} \leq \sum_{j\in \Gamma(A)} \sum_{i\sim j} w_{ij} = n |\Gamma(A)|.
$$
Thus from the locally finite version of Hall's marriage theorem (which follows from the usual version and compactness) we have an injection $f:U\to V$ such that $f(i) \sim i$ for each $i$. Now choose $A$ by selecting from each interval $I_i$ a point $a$ such that $\omega(a) \in I_{f(i)}$.